# How to identify final or dynamic value properties is bool or int in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

```
// FirstScreen

  final result = await  Get.to(SecondScreen());

//SecondScreen

//First button onTap
Get.back(result: 10)

//second buton onTap

 Get.back(result: true);
```

How can I identify the **result** is bool or int type when back to the second screen to the first screen.

Comment: You can check `result is bool` or `result is int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it with `is` like this:

```
if (result is int) {
  print("result is int");
}
else if (result is bool) {
  print("result is bool");
}
```